# How to echo table vertically when using PHP code?

Tags: php, html, html-table, border

I am trying to echo out the record of event in the website from database server. The  code below presents the records in horizontal format however I want it as vertically.

Echo.php file

```
<?php
  //Connect to database
  $con=mysqli_connect("#", "#", "", "#");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  //Query to select all publications from the 'files' table
  $result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY event_date DESC LIMIT 4");

  //Echo out table
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  //Echo out the publication details
  {
  echo "<table class='table' border='0'>
<tr>
     <td>
        <a href='business_profile.php?id={$row['event_id']}'> ".$row['event_name'] ." </a>
        </td>
     <td>
     <img width='190' height='180' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['event_pic'])."'/>
     </td>
     <td>" . $row['event_info'] . "</td>
</tr>";

  echo "</table>";
  }
   ?>
```

Currently it presents,

event1 event1_pic event1_info

event2 event2_pic event2_info ..so on

However I want the code to present as below in a block

event1 event 2

event1_pic event2_pic

event1_info  event3_pic

Comment: Stop putting only 1 td in each tr. You are explicitly telling the table to be 1 column.

Comment: you're also closing your table outside of your loop close it inside

Comment: @Dave, How do I do that? any tips

Comment: @Dave, I have made some changes, please observe the code above. here I have tried to close the table inside the wile loop however it is still giving me the same problem.

Comment: because of how you want to do it you're going to have to multiple loop through your result set sql databases are row based and you want to convert rows to column so effectively you need to loop once for titles (event 1, event 2) etc then loop again for pictures then loop again for info.

Comment: @Dave, Okay I will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

the

```
<tr>
```

tag is a table row. you can put multiple

```
<td>
```

tags to create table cells on each row. Example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
</tr>
```

This will quickly familiarize you with basic html table structure:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: the rows and columns are added automatically when I add a new record in the database therefore I cannot set a fixed table features.

Comment: of course you can you already are in your code above just your html is wrong.

Comment: I was not providing you with the exact code you need to use, just attempting to teach you how tables work so you can figure out how best to use html tables for your purposes.